# What is the distribution of pronominal "one"?

Tags: syntax, english, pronouns

(Based on the comments this question has received, more is needed to avoid confusion. The original question remains as stated below the line below. What is added here now is a more complete rendition that can avoid confusion.)

There are two versions of the word *one* in English, the cardinal number *one* and the pronominal count noun *one*. My question concerns the distribution of the latter. Why is the appearance of the pronominal count noun *one* immediately after certain determiners (i.e. weak determiners: *a, my, your, his, her, our, their,* etc.) marginal to bad for many speakers. Some examples are next:

(1) I like your pets. *Do you like my **ones**? vs. Do you like **mine**?

(2) Your kittens are cute, *but their **ones** are cuter. vs. but **theirs** are cuter.

(3) Our pastries are good, *but your **ones** are better vs. but **yours** are better.

The plural *ones* is used in these examples to avoid confusion with cardinal *one*, for plural *ones* is necessarily the pronominal count noun; the cardinal number *one* is always singular (of course).

The fascinating aspect of this phenomenon is that the examples just produced become fully acceptable if an adjective appears between the determiner and *ones*:

(1') I like your small pets. Do you like my big **ones**?

(2') Your gray kittens are cute, but their black **ones** are cuter.

(3') Our European pastries are good, but your Asian **ones** are better.

So my question concerns this mysterious state of affairs. What explains the inability of the pronominal count noun *one(s)* to appear immediately after a weak determiner?

---

The following data set illustrates a mysterious aspect of the distribution of the indefinite pronominal count noun *one* in English:

(1) *a one, *my one, *your one, *his one, *her one, *its one, *our one, *their one

(2) a big one, my big one, your big one, his big one, her big one, its big one, our big one, their big one

(3) the one, this one, that one, these ones, those ones

(4) the big one, this big one, that big one, these big ones, those big ones

Why are the examples in (1) bad, whereas the similar examples in (2-4) are fine? What literature addresses this phenomenon directly?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106418/discussion-on-question-by-tim-osborne-what-is-the-distribution-of-pronominal-on).

Answer (score 2):

I will now attempt to answer my own question. I believe the distribution of strong vs. weak forms in Germanic is the core explanation for the curious acceptability contrast produced in the question. Modern German provides a clue in this regard. Adjectives following certain determiners in German, which can be called *strong* determiners, take endings that are distinct from adjectives that follow certain other determiners, which can be called *weak* determiners. It can be assumed that this distinction between strong and weak determiners (and strong and weak endings) exists across Germanic languages more generally. What we can observe, then, is that the pronominal count noun *one(s)* in English is licensed by a preceding strong determiner or by what would be a preceding strong form in Germanic. If no such strong determiner or strong form appears, the pronominal count noun *one* cannot appear -- but cardinal *one* CAN, of course.

The next data set from German illustrates the core observation:

(1)  das klein-e Haus 'the small house'

(2)  ein klein-es Haus 'a small house'

The definite article (*der*, *die*, *das*, etc.) is a strong determiner. After this strong determiner, the ending that appears on the adjective (just *-e*) is weak. In contrast, the indefinite article *ein-* in (2) is a weak determiner. After this weak determiner, the ending that appears on the adjective is strong.

The pronominal count noun *one(s)* in English can appear immediately after the English versions of those determiners in German that are strong. It cannot appear immediately after the English versions of those determiners in German that are weak. The observed correspondence across the languages is almost complete. The next table lists the weak determiners across the languages:

[image]

The pronominal count noun *one(s)* cannot appear immediately after almost any one of the weak determiners listed in this table. If it immediately follows a strong determiner, however, it CAN appear. The strong determiners across English and German are given in the next table:

[image]

Switching now to the fact that pronominal *one(s)* can appear immediately after an adjective following a weak determiner (e.g. *my ones vs. my big ones), the intervening adjective would have a strong ending in German (e.g. *ein klein-es Haus*). Thus, the relevant generalization is that **the pronominal count noun *one(s)* in English must be licensed by what would be a preceding strong form in Germanic**, be this strong form a strong determiner or a strong inflectional suffix on an adjective.

The plausibility of this explanation is of course reliant on demonstrating that the relevant pattern existed in earlier forms of English. Certainly we know that Old English had the morphological richness associated with modern German. My coauthor is currently investigating the extent to which the observed pattern did or did not exist in Old and Middle English.

Comment: Would that approach mean having to regard *one* as cardinal in sentences like *I'll get one from the shop*, i.e. as having the same function as *two* in *I'll get two from the shop*?

Comment: Yes. But that is not new. Huddleston and Pullum (2002) already make that assumption.

Comment: Strong and weak declensions did indeed exist in Old English, but even without checking very deeply, I’m quite certain they did not survive far into Middle English. It lasted longest in monosyllabics, but even there, by late Middle English, it was gone – the weak ending _-e_ had become a simple orthographic variant. The real question this answer poses is thus when the construction _my one_ arose. I’d be very surprised if it dates all the way back to ME, much less OE – I would guess it’s a construction that’s arisen within the past 2–300 years, which would weaken this argument.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet I do not follow your reasoning. The construction _my one_, where _one_ is prominal _one_ (not cardinal _one_), is marginal to bad for many speakers. If some accept it, though, then that would be consistent with the assumption that it has entered the language only recently and is not yet widely accepted.

Comment: @TimOsborne Yes, but if it entered the language recently, and the strong/weak distinction disappeared long ago, then how are the two related? You cannot really argue that it arose to fill a gap that had been gone for centuries with no ill effects.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet OK, but I think, rather, that it is not so good for most modern speakers; it is certainly not good for me. So the question is, rather, how a distinction that existed centuries ago is able to survive  in remnant form for so long. I note that morphological case also died away from English centuries ago, yet the remnants of case survive in the pronoun system (_I_ vs. _me_, _he_ vs. _him_, etc.)

Comment: All the commenters who’ve mentioned that the construction is perfectly normal and unremarkable (that includes me – apart from _its one(s)_, which is clumsy, all the examples are perfectly commonplace to me, though colloquial) have been British. It is perhaps ungrammatical or infelicitous to most _non-British_ speakers, but not to most Brits. Even so, unlike pronominal case, which is an unbroken continuation, this is probably a _broken_ chain. The cases are remnants: they’ve been there all along. This would have to have disappeared completely, then much later suddenly appear again from nowhere.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Would you write it? If not, why not?

Comment: @TimOsborne I would, in informal writing. In a text to a mate or a comment on here, sure; in a business letter, probably not. Conversely, I might write “whether it be…” in a business letter, but not likely in a text to a mate.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet I've done some quick searches in the British National Corpus: _which ones_ occurs 141 times, _these ones_ occurs 86 times, _those ones_ occurs 56 times, _the ones_ occurs 1859 times. In contrast, _his ones_ occurs 1 time, _our ones_ occurs 2 times, _my ones_ occurs 5 times, and _your ones_ occurs 2 times. These numbers are, at the very least, supportive of my claims insofar as they demonstrate that pronominal _ones_ occurs rarely after weak determiners in written (British) English, whereas it occurs readily after strong determiners in written (British) English.

Comment: The most striking thing about pronominal *one* in the history of linguistics is that has given rise to so many [mythical claims about its distribution](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/Anaphoric_One.pdf). I find the Brigham Young corpuses a bit temperamental with *one*. Here's some Googlebooks result for [a few ones](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22a+few+ones%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in describing speakers' knowledge of these contrasts, then you should take a look at Richard Kayne's (2017) paper 'English One and Ones as Complex Determiners.'

He notes that adjectives need to have some sort of informational focus in order to license 'one.' For instance he gives:

People who read interesting books generally profit considerably from the reading of those interesting books/*ones

Also, what determines whether a determiner is 'strong' or 'weak' in English for you? A number of determiners normally considered 'strong' like 'most' don't allow bare 'one'/'ones':

I was surprised to like the movie; I don't like most movies/*ones.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will certainly take a look at Kayne's paper. Your comment about informational focus points to something I was aware of, although I have characterized the observation in terms of contrastive focus. Concerning _most_, it appears to be weak. I note, however, that its German equivalent, i.e. _die meisten_, is complex and is therefore better viewed as strong. There therefore appears to be a mismatch across the languages, although that is perhaps not a problem, since there is no clear correspondence due to the definite article _die_ appearing with _meisten_ but not with _most_.

Comment: If you are going to count *most*, *any*, *some* etc. as determiners then I suspect some version of your rule is valid regardless of dialect, and what changes is just the set of strong determiners. I hadn't been considering them as determiners at all though. *There are a few ones left on the shelf* is marginal to bad for me but otherwise anything with a quantifier is just impossible.